# Position a HTML table so that row index X is at top of display just below the header

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Using Codeigniter framework, I am loading an HTML table with a PHP foreach loop. The table can end up with many rows. Each row has an index. The table is scrollable so that the user can access rows which are not visible when the table is loaded. The user is able to edit a particular row.

Currently, after an edit is performed I am reloading the table so that the user can see his changes. However, the table is loaded starting at row index 1; This means that the edited row index X may be off the screen and the user needs to scroll to find it again.

I want to be able to load the table so that the edited row (row index x) is shown at the top of the display. The user would still be able to scroll forwards or backwards to access previous or future rows.

I have searched long and hard but have found nothing to help; maybe my terminology is wrong. My preference would be to do this without jquery as I am  trying to use pure HTML, PHP, CSS only.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div id="register_wrapper">

  <!-- Show item entry box -->
  <?php echo form_open( "receivings/add",array( 'id'=>'add_item_form')); echo form_input(array('name'=>'item','id'=>'item','size'=>'60')); ?>
    </form>

    <!-- Receiving Items List -->

    <table id="register">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th style="text-align:left;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('common_delete'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('DynamicKit'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('items_category'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('items_item_number'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:center;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_item_name'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('recvs_cost'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_edit'); ?>
          </th>
          <th style="text-align:right;">
            <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_quantity'); ?>
          </th>
          <?php if ($mode !='purchaseorder' ) { ?>
            <th style="text-align:center;">
              <?php echo $this->lang->line('items_dluo'); ?>
            </th>
            <?php } ?>
              <th style="text-align:right;">
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_discount'); ?>
              </th>
              <th style="text-align:right;">
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_total'); ?>
              </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody id="cart_contents">
        <?php $newcart='N' ; if(count($cart)==0) { $newcart='Y' ; ?>
          <tr>
            <td colspan='11'>
              <div class='warning_message' style='padding:7px;'>
                <?php echo $this->lang->line('sales_no_items_in_cart'); ?>
              </div>
          </tr>
          </tr>
          <?php } else { // if entire receipt do not reorder the cart; otherwise show in reverse order so that newly added items come out on top switch ($data[ 'entire_receipt']) { case 'Y': $foreach=$ cart; break; case 'N': default: $foreach=a rray_reverse($cart,
            true); } // read cart foreach ($foreach as $line=>$item) { // get item info $cur_item_info = $this->Item->get_info($item['item_id']); // point out that this is a dynamic kit constructed at run time. Let the user enter the parts // making up the kit and thier price $DynamicKit_settext = ' '; if
            ($cur_item_info->DynamicKit == 1) { $DynamicKit_settext = 'OUI'; } else { $DynamicKit_settext = ' '; } echo form_open("receivings/edit_item/$line"); ?>
            <tr>

              <!-- Output delete button -->
              <td>
                <?php echo anchor( "receivings/delete_item/$line", '['.$this->lang->line('common_delete').']');?>
              </td>

              <!-- Output Dynamic Kit indicator -->
              <td style="align:center;font-weight:bold;color:#161FDA">
                <?php echo $DynamicKit_settext ?>
              </td>

              <!-- Output category -->
              <td style="text-align:center;">
                <?php echo $item[ 'category']; ?>
              </td>

              <!-- Output item number -->
              <td style="text-align:center;">
                <?php echo $item[ 'item_number']; ?>
              </td>

              <!-- Output decription and qty in stock -->
              <td style="text-align:center;">
                <?php echo $item[ 'name']; ?>
              </td>

              <?php if ($items_module_allowed) { ?>
                <td style="text-align: right">
                  <?php echo form_input(array( 'name'=>'price', 'value'=>$item['price'], 'style'=>'text-align:right', 'size'=>'6')); ?>
                </td>
                <?php } else { ?>
                  <td style="text-align: right">>
                    <?php echo $item[ 'price']; ?>
                  </td>
                  <?php echo form_hidden( 'price',$item[ 'price']); ?>
                    <?php } ?>

                      <!-- output update item box -->
                      <td style="text-align: right">
                        <?php echo form_submit( "edit_item", $this->lang->line('sales_edit_item'));?>
                      </td>

                      <!-- Output quantity -->
                      <td style="text-align: right">
                        <?php echo form_input(array( 'name'=>'quantity', 'value'=>number_format($item['quantity'], 2), 'style'=>'text-align:right', 'size'=>'3')); ?>
                      </td>

                      <!-- Output DLUO -->
                      <?php if ($mode !='purchaseorder' ) { ?>
                        <td style="text-align: center">
                          <?php if ($cur_item_info->dluo_indicator == 'Y') { echo anchor ( 'items/dluo_form/'.$cur_item_info->item_id.'/DR', $this->lang->line('items_dluo') ); } else { echo ' '; } ?>
                        </td>
                        <?php } ?>

                          <!-- output discount field -->
                          <td style="text-align: right">
                            <?php echo form_input(array( 'name'=>'discount', 'value'=>$item['discount'], 'style'=>'text-align:right', 'size'=>'3')); ?>
                          </td>

                          <!-- output price field without tax -->
                          <td style="text-align: right">
                            <?php echo to_currency($item[ 'price']*$item[ 'quantity']-$item[ 'price']*$item[ 'quantity']*$item[ 'discount']/100); ?>
                          </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height:3px">
              <td colspan=10 style="background-color:#EEFFFF"></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
            <?php } } ?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you please share some of your code. For example, how the scrollable-feature of the table is it managed ?

Comment: When you reload the table, do you refresh your page or do it with js?

Comment: Pete, I refresh the page; I do not use JS.

Comment: a possible solution would be saving the table row's offset to a cookie before refreshing, then using the cookie value with $(document).scrollTop(your_stored_value_here); to scroll the page, then removing the cookie value (or simply set it to 0) so it won't interfere with future page loads.

Comment: Eria, I added the code snippet

Comment: José, this looks interesting. I can obtain the table row offset, no problem, but how do I implement your code? Is it JS or jquery? As I said I would rather not use these but if its the only solution, then so be it.

Comment: that´s JQuery. i would use JQuery to get the vertical offset of the edited row, save it to a cookie, then use JQuery again to scroll the window to the stored position. then set the cookie to 0 again. you can do it without using javascrip too, but it takes more coding.

Answer (score 0):

Give your table rows ID's

```
<tr id="Item-<?=$item['item_id']?>">
```

and then reload with the id in the URL

```
http://example.com/segment1/segment2/#Item-123
```

This should make the browser scroll to the right row of the table.

Hope this helps - Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK, I solved this using ideas from Steven M and from José. Thanks to both of you.

I'm using Chrome as the browser.

What I did,

Using HTML and CSS.

First I trapped the line id of the table row, which I stored in a cookie.
Second, on table reload, I tested the current table line id against the line id stored in the cookie.
Third, if same, I applied a CSS ID to the 'tr' tag in order to change the background colour of the table row. 
Fourth, if same, I applied autofocus to one of the input fields using the 'td' tag.

What I achieved,

1) changed table row is highlighted to show the user which table row he changed
2) the table row is now made visible within the viewport even if the user had to scroll to it. Its autofocus that worked.

Here is the code from the view for the tr tag

```html
// colour the line I just processed.
    if ($_SESSION['line'] == $line)
    {
    ?>
     <tr id="line_colour">
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
     <tr >
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the code for the td tag

```html
if ($_SESSION['line'] == $line)
    {
    ?>
     <td >
     <?php echo form_input(array(
            'name'     => 'quantity',
            'value'     => number_format($item['quantity'], 2),
            'style'     => 'text-align:right;background:pink',
            'size'     => '3',
            'autofocus'    => 'autofocus'
            ));
     ?>
     </td>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
     <td style="text-align: right">
     <?php echo form_input(array(
            'name'=>'quantity',
            'value'=>number_format($item['quantity'], 2),
            'style'=>'text-align:right',
            'size'=>'3'));
     ?>
     </td>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Here is the CSS,

```css
tr#line_colour
  {
   background-color:lightgreen;
   border-radius:8px;
  }
```

I stored the row line number in the cookie in the controller.

Hope this helps someone.